# Observable sub property String to listbox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

Sorry for what's probably a simple question.

I have a class Appointment which has various string properties.

I have an observable collection of them in my view model, however whenever I bind to any of the properties to a listbox it returns with every character for the first entry having it's own row

Sorry I don't have the code on hand, but to sum it up

```
сlass Appointment
{
    public Appointment(string ыubject)
    { 
        Subject = subject;
    }

    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

class Appointments
{ 
    public Appointments()
    { 
        ListOfAppointments = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>();
        ListOfAppointments.Add(new ListOfAppointments("Example"));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Appointment> ListOfAppointments { get; set; }
}
```

In the XAML:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource AppointementViewModel, Path=ListOfAppointments}" ItemSource="{Binding Subject }" />
```

Hoping that that is correct. The Results the listbox shows is

```
E
X
A
M
P
L
E
```

I'm pretty clue less at the moment and as I am not updating information after the initial fetch I do not have INotifyProperty implemented

Please note the data is being loaded correctly this is just a quick example to replicate.

Also if I use linq in the backend to query it it returns the correct results however as the actual implementation has more than one field that would be a cumbersome workaround. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ListBox itemsSource should be ListOfAppointments and in the datatemplate you can bind the subject property

```
<ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource AppointementViewModel}" ItemSource="{Binding ListOfAppointments}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

In the code sample given in the question, `ListOfAppoinments` is given as the `DataContext` of the `ListBox` and `Subject` as the `ItemsSource`. So the ListBox is taking the Subject property from the first object in ListOfAppoinments as its ItemsSource. So the string is split and assigned to each `ListBoxItem`.

In the above code, we have given the `ListOfAppoinments` as the `ItemsSource`. So each `Appointment` object is taken from the list and assigned to the `ListBoxItems`. Since we have bound `Subject` to the `TextBlock` in the `DataTemplate`, that will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you it does work and will implement this fix tomorrow, however I'm wondering why it's breaking out the string into characters? Yet if I select subject in a backend property using LINQ it ends up binding perfectly. Thanks for the help again.